# StackExchange.Redis ListRightPop not waiting for result

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to write a producer/consumer system using Redis in C#. Each message produced must be consumed by only one consumer, and I want the consumers to wait for elements created by the consumer. My system must support many produced/consumer sets.

I am using `StackExchange.Redis` to communicate with Redis, and using lists where elements are added using `ListLeftPush` and removed with `ListRightPop`. What I am experiencing is that while the `ListRightPop` method should block until an element exists in the list (or after a defined timeout), it always returns automatically if there are no elements in the list. This is the test code I wrote to check this:

```
IDatabase cache = connection.GetDatabase();        
Trace.TraceInformation("waiting "+DateTime.Now);
var res = cache.ListRightPop("test");
Trace.TraceInformation("Got "+res+", Ended" + DateTime.Now);
```

And I'm getting a `nil` result after less than 1 second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard pop operations do not block: they return nil if the list is empty or does not exist.

SE.Redis is a multiplexer. Using a blocking pop is a very very bad idea. This is explained more, with workarounds discussed specifically for blocking pops, in the documentation: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers

Comment: As usual, it's best to go straight to the source.

Comment: Marc - thanks for the pointer and for the great framework! Will try this out. Still, does this means that we perform two round trips to the cache server? Greatly reduces the performance of the solution :-(

Comment: @vainolo no, it doesn't mean that - especially if you "fire and forget" the broadcast. They pipeline very nicely. As for pub/sub generally: it is astonishingly fast - it is how we power our web-sockets server for live updates here on stackoverflow, which has 6 digit numbers of connected clients.

Comment: @MarcGravell Hi. The link is broken . [However there is a situation where I do need blocking BRPOP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48209466/859154). So like the OP asked , how can I block BRPOP ? ( or other alternative)?

Comment: @Royi fixing link

Comment: Marc , if so  , what is the alternative to block BLRPOP ? I need to wait for a publish  , but dont wont the fire-and-forget of pub/sub...

Comment: @Royi blocking operations basically kill scalability. Nothing can use the pipe while that happens. That might be fine for a single threaded server, in which case: maybe try with Execute - but: it will be bad for anything highly concurrent like a web server. If you are in the web server scenario, maybe "poll with pub/sub as a fast wake-up" (so there is always a fallback in case pub/sub fails)

Comment: Marc  Thanks for the replies.So according to the docs [is this the right approach](https://i.imgur.com/V9XSDge.jpg)  ? But this leaves me with a problem. What if a `publish` was made _before_ channel has been subscribed ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I absolutely *would not* be subscribing per-login here, so there is no "before" in my mind. To me, the channel would be generic and it is the *payload* that would be specific to the login - i.e. `publish "channel" "somevalue"` - then the consumer can activate *either* because they saw the publish *with their value* (no extra subscription here, note - just tracking "who is outstanding") - *or* because they hit some time limit and double-checked the data store (list, set, whatever you chose to use to define membership)

Comment: Marc , sorry for my stupidity : but if users do login to an Asp.net server which needs redis for sending command to other server for check that login --- does each request thread would do `subsribe(channel)?` and how would john's login request would know that the publish he has just recieved is _his_ ? According to what you say, John's login request will also have to investigate _other login responses_ just to check if it's his. am i wrong here? In other words - how would i pause john's aspnet  request thread until his login response from redis arrives?

Comment: @RoyiNamir "how would john's login request would know that the publish he has just recieved is his" - by the *content* of the result; but more generally: there would be only *one* bit of code handling those responses. The exchange here is pretty odd, though - I'm pretty sure this isn't how I would design a login system in the first place... but if I *had* to do this - probably something like https://gist.github.com/mgravell/8e13d0bc98a3c9152ebd6a2959c8a3d4 (pseudocode)

Comment: @MarcGravell After reading the reply and doing some thinking - [I think i've managed to do this completely `async + john request <--> response`](https://i.imgur.com/ZMQhaC8.jpg) . Is that a viable solution ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir that looks like a slow leak to me; who is unsubscribing? when?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163056/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-marc-gravell).

Answer (score 2):

StackExchange.Redis is merely hitting the redis server's exposed API, the relevant method of which is `BRPOP` in your case. The documentation for that is:

http://redis.io/commands/blpop - blocking left pop

http://redis.io/commands/brpop - blocking right pop

While those methods do describe the blocking behavior you are looking for, I believe SE.Redis `ListRightPop` is calling

http://redis.io/commands/rpop - right pop

I may not be up to the latest SE.Redis package, but intellisense is not giving me an option to supply a timeout like you claim. Additionally, there does not appear to be any methods starting with `.List` in the `IDatabase` interface that has the word "block" in it, so I'm not sure SE.Redis exposes a Redis `BRPOP` API. You can either write your own or ask Marc Gravell nicely, but this is a pretty big request I think because of the blocking nature of the call and the way the multiplexer works.

Comment: Good answer. Purely for your interest, blocking pops are discussed at length here: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/PipelinesMultiplexers.md