# Using Redis to implement login?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

We're using Redis to implement login mechanism between 2  servers over a vpn.

So basically it's  :

[image]

How we did it ?

At  `server1` side we do :

```
string RandomNum = Guid.NewGuid().Tostring("N"); 
sub.Subscribe("DO_LOGIN"+RandomNum,(channel,message)=>{ //listen to specific (!) response
 ...
});
sub.Publish("Do_LOGIN",{ ...data  , RandomNum});
```

While `server2` is already listening via :

```
sub.Subscribe("DO_LOGIN",(channel,message) =>
{
    //read message values + extract RandomNum from the message
    //check DB if user OK
    sub.Publish("DO_LOGIN"+RandomNum, ...data);
});
```

So as you can see- for every login I generate a number and command and then listen to a new channel which is concatenation of `"command"+RandomNum`

But we feel that this is a wrong path to go. Because all of those temp subscriptions.

**Question:**

Is it possible to implement login mechanism without temp subscriptions ?
*(unless this is how it should be)*

*NB We're using StackExchange.Redis*

Comment: I don't quite understand what "login" means in the context, but I would consider using Redis Lists and blocking pops instead of PubSub here.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Login is just a command that I publish from server1 to server2 and server 2 checks if valid credentials and publish again . So I use redis as a pipe to connect to other server rather than _storing_ credentials on redis

Comment: Then use a queue (a List) :)

Comment: @ItamarHaber Ok  - so let's see - a user enters credentials in server1 and then what ?

Comment: Answered (loving the user pic in the diag btw ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use two Lists for this type of distributed pattern instead. I'm suggesting this mainly because of PubSub's nature of "shoot and forget" without guaranteeing delivery. I would assume that in your case, your do not want that.

Here's the suggested flow - first you'll need to set up two blocking "listeners":

1. Server1: `BRPOP completed`
2. Server2: `BRPOP requests`

Then, when a user logs in:

1. Server1: `LPUSH requests data`
2. Server2: unblocks, processes data, `LPUSH completed data` and go back to blocking pop
3. Server1: unblocks, does whatever, go back to blocking pop

Comment: Wow I didnt know that getting a value in pub sub is not guaranteed (even if there's a subscriber listening ??). Thanks

Comment: PubSub provides "at-most-once delivery" semantics - it is what it is :)

Comment: Itamar - rethinking about this , if John is doing login  , in other words John do `LPUSH requests data` and meanwhile - Paul is also doing login so it also does `LPUSH requests data` , but let's say that Paul's login logic is much _faster_ than John's login logic. So `server2` sends Paul's response by `LPUSH completed data` **first**. How would `server1` know/attach requests to response ?

Comment: In other words , sould I do the same like my question as : `lpush "DOLOGIN"+RandomNumber` and listen by the matching `brpop "DOLOGIN"+RandomNumber` ?